# Doctrine 2 and codeigniter 2, how to use generated code

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

Working a few months with CodeIgniter, newbe with Doctrine.
I work recently with https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2 as the base and defining entities from mysql table/columns with `generate_classes()` function (*application/libraries/Doctrine.php, called once before constructor ends, comment it after entities created)*:

**application/libraries/Doctrine.php**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator;
/**
 * CodeIgniter Smarty Class
 *
 * initializes basic doctrine settings and act as doctrine object
 *
 * @final   Doctrine
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author  Md. Ali Ahsan Rana
 * @link    http://codesamplez.com/
 */
class Doctrine
{
  /**
   * @var EntityManager $em
   */
  public $em = null;

  /**
   * constructor
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
    require APPPATH . 'config/database.php';

    // Set up class loading. You could use different autoloaders, provided by your favorite framework,
    // if you want to.
    require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', APPPATH . 'libraries');
    $doctrineClassLoader->register();
    $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, "/"));
    $entitiesClassLoader->register();
    $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', APPPATH . 'models');
    $proxiesClassLoader->register();

    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache  = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(
      APPPATH . 'models/Entities'
    ));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH . 'models/proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    // Set up logger
    //$logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    //$config->setSQLLogger($logger);

    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(TRUE);
    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
      'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
      'user' => $db['default']['username'],
      'password' => $db['default']['password'],
      'host' => $db['default']['hostname'],
      'dbname' => $db['default']['database']
    );

    // Create EntityManager
    $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

    /* Generate entity objects automatically from mysql db tables. Run once.
     * http://codesamplez.com/development/using-doctrine-with-codeigniter
     */
    //$this->generate_classes();
  }

  /**
   * generate entity objects automatically from mysql db tables
   * @return none
   */
  function generate_classes()
  {
    $this->em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl(new DatabaseDriver($this->em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()));

    $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
    $cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
    $metadata  = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
    $generator = new EntityGenerator();

    $generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
    $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
    $generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
    $generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH . "models/Entities");

  }

}
```

Generated files:

**application/models/Entities/Customers.php**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Customers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customers
{
  /**
   * @var integer $idCustomer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id_customer", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $idCustomer;

  /**
   * @var string $customerName
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="customer_name", type="string", length=62, nullable=false)
   */
  private $customerName;

  /**
   * @var CustomerAges
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomerAges")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_customer_age", referencedColumnName="id_customer_age")
   * })
   */
  private $idCustomerAge;


  /**
   * Get idCustomer
   *
   * @return integer 
   */
  public function getIdCustomer()
  {
    return $this->idCustomer;
  }

  /**
   * Set customerName
   *
   * @param string $customerName
   * @return Customer
   */
  public function setCustomerName($customerName)
  {
    $this->customerName = $customerName;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get customerName
   *
   * @return string 
   */
  public function getCustomerName()
  {
    return $this->customerName;
  }

  /**
   * Set idCustomerAge
   *
   * @param CustomerAges $idCustomerAge
   * @return Customers
   */
  public function setIdCustomerAge(\CustomerAges $idCustomerAge = null)
  {
    $this->idCustomerAge = $idCustomerAge;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get idCustomerAge
   *
   * @return CustomerAges 
   */
  public function getIdCustomerAge()
  {
    return $this->idCustomerAge;
  }
}
```

**application/models/Entities/Customer_ages.php**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * CustomerAges
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer_Ages")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CustomerAges
{
  /**
   * @var integer $idCustomerAge
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id_customer_Age", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $idCustomerAge;

  /**
   * @var integer $AgeNumber
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="Age_number", type="integer", nullable=false)
   */
  private $AgeNumber;

  /**
   * Get idCustomerAge
   *
   * @return integer 
   */
  public function getIdCustomerAge()
  {
    return $this->idCustomerAge;
  }

  /**
   * Set AgeNumber
   *
   * @param integer $AgeNumber
   * @return CustomerAges
   */
  public function setAgeNumber($AgeNumber)
  {
    $this->AgeNumber = $AgeNumber;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get AgeNumber
   *
   * @return integer 
   */
  public function getAgeNumber()
  {
    return $this->AgeNumber;
  }
}
```

**Edited:** How can I use it for [CRUD operations](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-day-5-database-crud) with related tables? I know, read the user guide, but (in example) if `$post = $entityManager->find("Customers", $idCustomer);` is for single row, which function/syntax returns all rows (and related)?

Comment: This is not doctrine 2. Doctrine 2 has a completely different way of defining entities..

Comment: @Broncha Thank you, edited and improved the question.

Comment: You should really go through the user guide and documentation for doctrine.. You can implement repositories for handling more than one rows. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

The following code should give you all the rows in the table.

```
$em->getRepository('Customers')->findAll();
```